# vuejs3 with Python Flask on Apache: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, vuejs3

I am a beginner with vuejs, my first day. I am trying to add some simple components based on this example to a pre-existing site running on Python Flask with Jinja:
https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/routing.html

In the /static folder, I have created an index.html file as below:

```
<script type="importmap">
{
  "imports": {
    "vue": "https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.js"
  }
}
</script>
<script type="module">
  import Home from './Home.vue'
  import About from './About.vue'
  import NotFound from './NotFound.vue'

  const routes = {
    '/': Home,
    '/about': About
  }

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        currentPath: window.location.hash
      }
    },
    computed: {
      currentView() {
        return routes[this.currentPath.slice(1) || '/'] || NotFound
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      window.addEventListener('hashchange', () => {
        this.currentPath = window.location.hash
      })
    }
  }
  </script>

  <template>
    <a href="#/">Home</a> |
    <a href="#/about">About</a> |
    <a href="#/non-existent-path">Broken Link</a>
    <component :is="currentView" />
  </template>
```

The files Home.vue, About.vue and NotFound.vue are quite identical with code as below:

```
<template>
  <h1>About</h1>
</template>
```

When I try to load index.html I am getting this error in the console:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at Home.vue:1:1)**

In the Flask app I have set the mimetype for .vue files as below:

```
mimetypes.add_type('application/javascript', '.vue', True)
```

My understanding is this is the correct mimetype for .vue files. Based on my reading, .vue files should contain both markup and script as per SFC recommendations.

I have read many related questions and can confirm this is not a path issue. The browser does indeed try to load Home.vue but is not happy about the presence of HTML tags.

Appreciate any advice on how to solve this.

Comment: `.vue` files are expected to be Javascript.  You can't put markup in a Javascript import file.  Also, `import Home from './home.vue'` is going to try to import the symbol `Home` from that file.

Comment: But all the examples I saw at https://vuejs.org/ included markup in the .Vue files. In fact, home.vue is taken directly from one of their examples without any modification and only contained markup.

Comment: Hello @SteveKiss You're trying to access Home from your **Home.vue** but I think it does'nt exported Home from that file intead it is trying to access `<template>` which id not a valid so it should be a function with export keyword.

Comment: I think I understand what I was missing. Seems that Vue requires a build step..